# CSS Image Resize by Height

Tags: html, css

I am aware of the image resizing technic of changing image proportions based on width:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I need to do the same thing only based on the height of the parent, not the width.  I have tried the following with no effect:

```
img{
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

I hope I explaining this well enough.

Please help :)

Comment: is `jquery` an option????

Comment: @NoobEditor http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question ;)

Comment: `width:100%;height:auto;`

Comment: @BenM : hmmm...got the hint!! :p

Comment: Yes jQuery is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height` will only restrict the height to be less than the given value.

If you want it to be the same as its parent.. give it as `height: 100%`

hence this should work:
CSS:

```
img{
  height: 100%; // changed max-height to height here
  width: auto; // this is optional
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot effectively base it on the height using standard css techniques, but you can make the `height` relate directly to the `width` of the image for a more flexible layout. Try this:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;     /* desired width */
}
img:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this and it worked .

```
    <div class="parent">
    <img src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2014/07/google-logo-sign-1920-600x337.jpg" alt="..." />
</div>


.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

see it here
https://jsfiddle.net/shuhad/vaduvrno/